# Error while building opencv with mingw and cmake : "windres.exe: invalid option -- W"

Tags: opencv, cmake, windows-10, mingw

I am trying to build opencv 3.4 source with mingw and cmake. I have configured & generated with cmake, then using admin powershell i run `mingw32-make.exe` in the build directory chosen in cmake

Here are the last lines of output:

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to disable precompiled headers in CMake when building opencv with mingw compiler.

[image]